# Android Account Authenticator edit Email Id Credentials

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-account, android-authenticator

When i login with **test1@gmail.com** in my application.It generate account successfully with my email like this

[image]

Now i logout and login with different email like **test2@gmail.com** then it generate account like this

[image]

I want to know that which is the best way

**1) Remove first account and add second account**

**2) Update first account with second if it is possible to update it.**

---

#### What is Problem I am getting actually?

If I remove and again add account using `addAccountExplicitly` it takes some time for creating new account so my next code is executed and **account** returns **null.**

Is is possible to update account using the help of `updateCredentials` if yes then how ??

## Edited:

What I do actually?

- Creating bundle with required data for account
- Checking whether **account** already exists with local inserted bundle params "global_user_id", If it is already exists then I have to update **EMAIL** which is used as login (see above images.)
- Currently I am doing as, Removing old account and Adding new Account, but next line is for **SyncAdapter Configuration** which needs account. In that getting **NULL** because adding account takes some time in background.

Is there any other solution to update that **Email Id**?

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the account in the moment the user logs out?

Comment: @MariusBoepple nop, I just invalidate account access token.

Comment: Okay, but if I logout in an App, I don't want to see my Account anymore in the settings... Nevertheless I would like to know how to change the Email, because I'm using the AccountAuthenticator and user may want to change his email address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got solution of this problem.

Question: **Removing/Adding Account remains null `account` object**

## Solution 1:

First I removed account using `removeAccount()` and then tried to `addAccountExplicitly` BUT `removeAccount()` taking time to execute in **background thread** while **addAccountExplicitly** called and doing further process.

So I changed my flow, as I used **`removeAccount`** method of **AccountManager** class and doing whole process in that handler, So I write my code inside the callback area.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
     mAccountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], LoginActivity.this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
         @Override
         public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {

             // Creating the account on the device and setting the auth token we got
             // (Not setting the auth token will cause another call to the server to authenticate the user)
             mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, intent.getBundleExtra(AccountManager.KEY_USERDATA));
             mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authTokenType, authToken);

             /**
              * Setting for Sync Adapter
              * Syncing Configuration
              */
              SyncAdapter.configSyncAdapter(mContext);
        }
    }, null);

} else {

    mAccountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], new AccountManagerCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> future) {

            // Creating the account on the device and setting the auth token we got
            // (Not setting the auth token will cause another call to the server to authenticate the user)
            mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, intent.getBundleExtra(AccountManager.KEY_USERDATA));
            mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authTokenType, authToken);

            /**
             * Setting for Sync Adapter
             * Syncing Configuration
             */
             SyncAdapter.configSyncAdapter(mContext);
        }
    }, null);
}
```

## Solution 2:

I found method called **[renameAccount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#renameAccount(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20android.os.Handler))** but it require minimum sdk version 21.
As per docs:

> Rename the specified Account. This is equivalent to removing the
>   existing account and adding a new renamed account with the old
>   account's user data.
>
> It is safe to call this method from the main thread.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

when you create/remove account, it executes that task in different thread(background thread) and thus it goes to next line which may have null value.

**Solution**

Step 1.
you should use [addOnAccountsUpdatedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(android.accounts.OnAccountsUpdateListener,%20android.os.Handler,%20boolean)) for receiving callback to your main thread.

Step 2.
you will receive callback on [onAccountsUpdated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/OnAccountsUpdateListener.html#onAccountsUpdated(android.accounts.Account[])) of [OnAccountsUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/OnAccountsUpdateListener.html)

Step 3.
Once you receive callback, you may put your next code over there inside that method. i.e.: SyncAdapter configuration

Step 4. 
Don't forget to get rid of listener which you had registered, otherwise you will suffer from memory leak. So use [removeOnAccountsUpdatedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeOnAccountsUpdatedListener(android.accounts.OnAccountsUpdateListener)) once you're done.

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: Actually your answer is useful only whenever user change their profile, but I have different flow as I have to change on logout/login also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete first account and then add the new one. As far as your problem about the code which executes before  your account is executed you can control this by

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this); //this is Activity
Account account = new Account("MyAccount","com.company.demo.account.DEMOACCOUNT");
boolean success = accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account,"password",null);
if(success){
    Log.d(TAG,"Account created");
}else{
    Log.d(TAG,"Account creation failed. Look at previous logs to investigate");
}
```

Just check the success boolean. And do your work accordingly :)

Comment: its goes to else part, I think because of already account is exists. (before adding account, I am removing account and may be its not removed at that moment.)

Comment: May be that is the problem , but the code here is working fine , Just check for the email when it is removed :) @PratikButani